# How to save all csv record in LIST in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

For Example:
from("file:{{catalog.file.path}}?maxMessagesPerPoll=5&move=processed")
                .to(ESBConstants.SEDA_ARRAY_TO);

```
    /* sending it to seda array */
    from("seda:array?concurrentConsumers=5&waitForTaskToComplete=never&blockWhenFull=true")
            .to(ESBConstants.PRODUCT_SKU_CSV_TO);

    from(ESBConstants.PRODUCT_SKU_CSV_TO).split()
            .tokenize(ESBConstants.LINE_BREAK_TOKENIZER).doTry()
            .unmarshal(productCSVBindy)
            .to("direct:list");
```

from("direct:list").process("testProcessor").to("direct:someENdpoint");

this is my sample code , SO i need to know is there any way to save each record value in my 'testProcessor' and send it to "direct:someENdpoint".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Camel Aggregator for this.
http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html

Check this link it is almost same situation.
http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2014/01/how-to-implement-the-splitter-and-aggregator-patterns-with-apache-camel/